# An alternative to TaskEx.FromResult on a platform where it's not available

Tags: task-parallel-library, portable-class-library

I am converting a portable class library to use a different profile (78). Most of the changes were related to reflection API, and now I have few last lines that don't compile, all of them are using TaskEx.FromResult.

TaskEx.FromResult is handy when a method returns Task, and a value of T needs to be wrapped and returned from the method, e.g.:

```
public Task<int> ReturnTaskOfInt()
{
    return TaskEx.FromResult(42);
}
```

Unfortunately TaskEx is not available for some PCL profiles. Perhaps it shouldn't be hard to write a replacement for it, and I will appreciate an advise.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, it was damn easy. TaskEx.FromResult is not available, but Task.FromResult is there.